# Spring : order of <map> tag

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I need to Inject a Map to a bean property and when map entries are traversed it should return them in insertion order. In Java, this is similar to the LinkedHashMap. But as I can't find anything in spring documentation related to the ordering of  tag, I'm not sure whether I can use to use it in this scenario.

Can someone please let me know the whether I can use  for this purpose.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default **is** `LinkedHashMap` - [`MapFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MapFactoryBean.html) is used to create instances of `Map`. According to docs:

> Simple factory for shared Map instances. Allows for central setup of
>   Maps via the "map" element in XML bean definitions.

and its [setTargetMapClass](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MapFactoryBean.html#setTargetMapClass%28java.lang.Class%29) method:

> Set the class to use for the target Map. Can be populated with a fully
>   qualified class name when defined in a Spring application context.
>   **Default is a linked HashMap, keeping the registration order.**
>
> See Also: LinkedHashMap

so no need to use `<util:map>` here.

Comment: That's better. Guess I can use that <map> for this then. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Use this construct:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

...
<util:map id="mymap" map-class="java.util.LinkedHashMap">
    <entry key="a" value="b" />
    <entry key="c" value="d" />
</util:map>

...
</beans>
```

to declare the map with ordered keys. You can then use this map using `<ref id="mymap" />` or you can use this construct directly while declaring the value of Map property.